# Convert custom spanish date time format into MySQL timestamp without truncating

Tags: php, mysql, date, format

I have the following dates (eg.)

27/01/2014 17:35
27/01/2014 20:32
28/01/2014 7:01
28/01/2014 12:59
29/01/2014 7:08
29/01/2014 12:58

I've used list() and explode() to convert date into MySQL format, but I still have problem with the time value, because when inserting the complete converted date MySQL truncates it and finally inserts **0000-00-00 00:00:00** into the field

How could I fill in the time value with zeroes so MySQL doesn't truncates? Thanks

Eg:

29/01/2014 12:58  should be 2014-01-29 12:58:00
29/01/2014 7:08  should be 2014-01-29 07:08:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `DateTime()` to convert the dates into the new format:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i', '27/01/2014 17:35');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/mybKlS)